# How to calculate next Friday?

Tags: python, datetime

How can I calculate the date of the next Friday?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A certain improvement on @taymon`s answer:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
friday = today + datetime.timedelta( (4-today.weekday()) % 7 )
```

4 is Friday's weekday (0 based, counting from Monday).
`( (4-today.weekday()) % 7)` is the number of days till next friday (`%` is always non-negative).

After seeing @ubuntu's answer, I should add two things:
1. I'm not sure if Friday=4 is universally true. Some people start their week on Sunday.
2. On Friday, this code returns the same day. To get the next, use `(3-today.weekday())%7+1`. Just the old `x%n` to `((x-1)%n)+1` conversion.

Comment: Friday is always 4 when using the [`weekday()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) method. The [`isoweekday()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) method gives Friday as 5, because it treats Monday through Sunday as 1 through 7.

Comment: You can use `calendar.FRIDAY` instead of `4` if you don't mind adding `import calendar`.

Comment: Can you please specify the code that returns the next Friday? I can’t understand it, I’m bad at math...I'm doing it for wednesday

Answer (score 55):

To start off, you'll need the `datetime` library:

```
import datetime
```

Then you need a starting date; that is, today.

```
d = datetime.date.today()
```

Starting from there, you'll want to keep going forward until you reach Friday. The `date.weekday` method represents Monday through Sunday as 0 through 6, so:

```
while d.weekday() != 4:
```

If the current day isn't Friday, you'll have to add a day, one at a time. To add an interval of time to a `date` object, you use a `timedelta` object.

```
    d += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Put it all together, and `d` will ultimately contain a `date` object representing next Friday. Note that if today is Friday, this code will produce today; you can tweak it if you need it to produce next Friday instead.

Answer (score 31):

Here is how you could do it using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.relativedelta as REL
today = DT.date.today()
print(today)
# 2012-01-10

rd = REL.relativedelta(days=1, weekday=REL.FR)
next_friday = today + rd
print(next_friday)
# 2012-01-13
```

(The `days = 1` argument ensures that the "next Friday" is not the same as `today` in case `today` happens to be a Friday.)

Answer (score 12):

I found this [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io) pretty useful. Just one line

```py
>>> pendulum.now().next(pendulum.FRIDAY).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2019-04-26'
```

Comment: Pendulum for the win. I wish all other modules die out.

Comment: This wins for  me too. ```nextMonday = pendulum.now().next(pendulum.MONDAY)
nextSunday = nextMonday.next(pendulum.SUNDAY)
nextMonday = nextMonday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
nextSunday = nextSunday.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')``` To get next Sunday after the next Monday.

Comment: sweet package! how can this be modified to return the current day if it's a Friday?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate any next day dates using these this code below.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def get_weekday(day):
    days  = ["mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun"]
    return days.index(day) + 1

def get_next_dayofweek_datetime(date_time, dayofweek):
    start_time_w = date_time.isoweekday()
    target_w = get_weekday(dayofweek)
    if start_time_w < target_w:
      day_diff = target_w - start_time_w
    else:
        day_diff = 7 - (start_time_w - target_w)

    return date_time + timedelta(days=day_diff)

def get_next_n_weekends_dates(date_time, weekday, n=2):
  days_list = []
  week_date_time = date_time
  while n > 0:
      week_date_time = get_next_dayofweek_datetime(week_date_time, weekday)
      days_list.append(week_date_time)
      n = n -1
  return  days_list

start_time = dt.strptime("2020-02-01 20:20:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # wednesday


print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "thu"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "fri"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "sat"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "sun"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "mon"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "tue"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "wed"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "thu"))

print("get next two fridays or mote ")
print(get_next_n_weekends_dates(start_time, "fri", 2))
```

output:

```
2020-02-06 10:20:00
2020-02-07 10:20:00
2020-02-08 10:20:00
2020-02-02 10:20:00
2020-02-03 10:20:00
2020-02-04 10:20:00
2020-02-05 10:20:00
2020-02-06 10:20:00
get next two fridays or mote 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7, 10, 20), datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 10, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for readability I would use strftime('%A') rather than weekday():

```
import datetime

d = datetime.date.today()

while d.strftime('%a') != 'Fri':
    d += datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Comment: If today is Friday, then it will not get the Friday from next week.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime 
def next_fri_13(start_date):
        next_friday = start_date + datetime.timedelta(((4 - today.weekday()) % 7))
        while True:
            if next_friday.day==13:
                thirteen_friday = next_friday
                break
            else:
                next_date = next_friday + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                next_friday = next_date + datetime.timedelta(((4 -next_date.weekday())% 7))
        return thirteen_friday

    r = next_fri_13(datetime.date(2020, 2, 11)) print(r)
```