# Python: Return the date of the next occurence of a third Thursday of the month

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar, datetimeoffset

I'm somewhat new to Python and I've been really struggling with solving what seems like a simple problem, but I'm noticing all this code piling up and I'm just getting lost in the sauce.

I just need the date of the next occurrence of a third Thursday of the month, whether it is the present month or the following month.

This is different than the possible duplicate problem because I'm not testing to find if a given date was a third Thursday, I am simply looking to spit out the next occurrence of a third Thursday at the time which the script is run.

I look forward to being able to make stuff like this (or solve much more complicated problems!) but I really need to get this code running for something right now. I'd be really grateful if you can help me solve my conundrum, and maybe leave me some useful comments in the process!

Thank you so much.

Comment: This is different than the possible duplicate problem because I'm not testing to find if a given date was a third Thursday, I am simply looking to spit out the next occurrence of a third Thursday at the time which the script is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? It outputs 2019-2-21 based on today being 1/19 and the third Thursday of Jan was 1/17. Basically used these other answers for a detailed explanation. This one was the original dup comment (that was deleted) - [How to calculate next Friday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801084/how-to-calculate-next-friday). Just ask if anything needs explanation.

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
next_thursday = today + datetime.timedelta(((3 - today.weekday()) % 7))
while True:
    if 15 <= next_thursday.day <= 21:
        next_third_thursday = next_thursday
        break
    else:
        next_date = next_thursday + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        next_thursday = next_date + datetime.timedelta(((3 - next_date.weekday()) % 7))

print(next_third_thursday)
```

Comment: oh my gosh. this is really elegant and I think I get most of it, at least superficially. Unfortunately, while it works locally, I'm getting errors when running it on Zapier. Might you know how I can fix this?


`File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 110, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.date(2019, 2, 21) is not JSON serializable`

Comment: I tried to serialize (which I don't yet understand) by converting the date to a string (which would be fine for my purposes, I think) and got this error:

`'unicode' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: Not sure what the data requirements of Zapier are, have you checked their documentation? Does it need valid JSON or something like a dict key/value pair? 
You can get a quoted string by using `import json` and then use `json.dumps(str(next_third_thursday))` - that will return "2019-02-21" (with quotes). Do you need to assign a key?

Comment: I'm still getting that same error with your fix, unfortunately. [here's the documentation](https://zapier.com/help/code-python/)

Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: This seems to be morphing into a new question. You'll probably be more successful posting a new question, with your code and error message appropriately tagged with Zapier. My code is python 3.7 and the Zapier intro from your link says "The environment is vanilla Python 2.7.10.", So, you should probably also include the versions of what you are using. Hopefully the Zapier wizards will be able to get you rolling.

Comment: ah. thank you SO MUCH for the help. I'll do just that!!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import pandas as pd
current_date = pd.Timestamp('Jan 20, 2019')
while True:
    if 15 <= current_date.day <= 21 and current_date.day_name() == 'Thursday':
        break
    current_date +=pd.DateOffset(1)

print(current_date)

#2019-02-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: unfortunately I won't have access to pandas where this needs to run. thank you so much, though!