# How can I add a function parameter to get days of current (default), previous or next week

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

My function returns days of the previous week. I want to replace this part:

```
- datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

with a function parameter that will receive 'prevweek', 'nextweek' or 'current'. Thanks.

```
import datetime

def days_of_week():
    days = []
    sunday = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
              - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7))
    friday = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
              - datetime.timedelta(days=(datetime.datetime.today().weekday() - 4) % 7,
                                                          weeks=-1))
    while sunday.date() <= friday.date():
        days.append(sunday.date())
        sunday += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return days
```

I thought maybe something like:

```
import datetime

def days_of_week(rel_week='current'):
  days = []
  week_options = {
      'prevweek''prevweek': datetime.timedelta(days=-7),
      'nextweek''nextweek': datetime.timedelta(days=7)7,
      'current': datetime.timedelta(days=0)0
  }
  sunday = (datetime.datetime.today() + f'{week_options[rel_week]}' +
            - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)
            + datetime.timedelta(days=week_options[rel_week])) 

  friday = (datetime.datetime.today() + f'{week_options[rel_week]}' +
            + datetime.timedelta(days=(4-datetime.datetime.today().weekday() - 4) % 7,)
                                                       + weeks=-1datetime.timedelta(days=week_options[rel_week]))
  print(sunday,friday)
  while sunday.date() <= friday.date():
      days.append(sunday.date())
      sunday += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  return days
```

Comment: Could you post the code you aren't able to get working?

Comment: I added my tries above. thx

Comment: I figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, and also found a bug where looking for friday of the current week. The solution for the bug were taken from [How to calculate next Friday?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8801084/9215309)

```
import datetime

def days_of_week(rel_week='current'):
   days = []
   week_options = {
       'prevweek': -7,
       'nextweek': 7,
       'current': 0
   }
   sunday = (datetime.datetime.today()
             - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)
             + datetime.timedelta(days=week_options[rel_week]))

   friday = (datetime.datetime.today()
             + datetime.timedelta(days=(4-datetime.datetime.today().weekday()) % 7)
             + datetime.timedelta(days=week_options[rel_week]))

   while sunday.date() <= friday.date():
       days.append(sunday.date())
       sunday += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   return days
```